# Jwplayer is cuting part of streaming video (MAC)

Tags: javascript, macos, video-streaming, rtmp, jwplayer6

JwPlayer is cutting part of live streaming video (at bottom or right), and this happing only for mac browsers. With same Windows browsers is working well.

Jwplayer code:

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
        sources: [{
            file: 'http://stream.streamexample.com/live/ngrp:live/jwplayer.smil',
        }, {
            file: 'http://stream.streamexample.com/live/ngrp:live/playlist.m3u8',
        }],
        rtmp: { bufferlength: 6 },
    title: 'Live',
    width: '854',
    height: '480',
    skin: 'jwplayer/glow-rtmp.xml',
    autostart: true,
    androidhls: true,
    });
```

JwPlayer size is same as streaming video size

I trayed add `stretching:"exactfit"` this also not helped

For streaming we use Wowza. Video is coded h.264 and we streaming with different qualities

JwPlayer version is 6.10

Chrome console give this error

```
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glTexImage2D: target was GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB
```

It's posible solve this or there is better alternative for jwplayer and live streaming.

Comment: Looks like this is known issue with that codec in Chrome :  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454251